# TabBar App Modal View Controller

Tags: xcode, tabbar

I am building a tab bar app one of the tabs has an image (image 1) with a modal view controller that flips horizontally to image 2.
Both images have buttons that display content.
When the buttons are tapped in image 1 the tab bar is hidden.
When When the buttons are tapped in image 2 the tab bar is displayed.

I want to hide the tab bar I have tried this code

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

from the sample code "The Elements" without response in this location of my program

```
- (IBAction)switchClinical:(id)sender;
{
    Clinical *second =[[Clinical alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
    [second release];

}
```

Any tips to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either presenting from `self.parentViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)switchClinical:(id)sender {
    Clinical *second =[[Clinical alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
    [second release];
}
```

or if your app delegate has a property for the tab bar:

```
- (IBAction)switchClinical:(id)sender {
    Clinical *second =[[Clinical alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).tabBar presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
    [second release];
}
```